# unmarchall object from REST request with Content-Type to application/xml

Tags: java, rest

I have a REST service which accepts request with `Content-Type = application/json` and caught object  and unmarshall it with Jackson. I want to change controller to accept request with `Content-Type = application/xml` instead json. Could u recommend me please some lib for that and rewrite model class and controller.

part of akka controller:

```
         post(() ->
            entity(
                Jackson.unmarshaller(User.class),
                user ->
                    onSuccess(createUser(user), performed -> {
```

model:

```
public final static class User {
    public final String name;

    @JsonCreator
    public User(@JsonProperty("name") String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use JAXB 2.0 for marshalling and unmarshalling. It is no third party library. It's a part of JDK only.